# Google Cloud SDK - No module named ipaddr

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

Today our development containers started throwing and error while running the App Engine (GAE) Standard local development environment from the Google Cloud SDK.

```
ERROR    2017-12-15 09:38:37,766 http_runtime.py:396] bad runtime process port ['']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/_php_runtime.py", line 103, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/_php_runtime.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/runtime/runtime.py", line 39, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import wsgi_server
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 34, in <module>
    import ipaddr
ImportError: No module named ipaddr
```

It looks like it was caused by an upgrade to the latest SDK which happened automatically.

Comment: I have the same issue on MacOS, Google Cloud SDK 183.0.0

Comment: Still occurring with GoogleAppEngine-1.9.67 released Monday, 12 February 2018

Answer (score 7):

Temporal solution for macOS, copy the [`ipaddr.py`](https://github.com/google/ipaddr-py/blob/master/ipaddr.py) file to `<google-cloud-sdk>/platform/google_appengine`

Comment: Fixed it for me. Note that if you still use the old launcher this isn't in ~/google-cloud-sdk but in /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 14.04, which we are using to match the GAE PHP version of 5.5, the python module they are trying to use isn't installed by default.

We installed it with:

```
# apt install python-ipaddr
```

This looks to be because of a feature they have introduced to do with host checking, to prevent DNS rebinding attacks.

Comment: Installing that library solved the issue experienced on Windows 10 for GAE PHP 5.5

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10, I copied the file `ipaddr.py` from https://github.com/google/ipaddr-py into the `Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\Lib\` folder and it worked.

Not an experienced Python coder, so I'm not sure if it's the best place to put the missing `ipaddr.py` file, but it works.

Comment: For what it's worth, this didn't work under my Win 10. I had to install 'ipaddr.py' under the '\Python\Lib\' folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

This happened after GoogleAppEngine-1.9.65 upgrade in my Windows 7 and it seems C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\ipaddr\ipaddr folder is missing ipaddr.py file.

I had to download [ipaddr-2.2.0.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/9d/a7/1b39a16cb90dfe491f57e1cab3103a15d4e8dd9a150872744f531b1106c1/ipaddr-2.2.0.tar.gz#md5=f88353e40dec06410acfa075b8209b27) then unzip it and run following command to install it.

```
python setup.py install
```

Hope this helps.